# Installing happylager demo site on own server (not locally)

Tags: install, 404

I would like to install the happylager demo site on my server instead of installing it locally,
but all i get is 404 pages when i visit http://adamridovics.com/happylager.dev/admin
Is this possible at all, or i am doing something worong?

Comment: Is it an Apache 404 or a Craft 404? Since you're installing Craft is a subfolder of an existing site, you may need to adjust Craft's public `.htaccess` file and/or your existing site's `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Thanks @BradBell , your comment made me recheck everything - i just forgot to take out the files from the public folder... now everything looks fine.

Comment: Sweet... can you add that as an official answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @BradBell , your comment made me recheck everything - i just **forgot to take out the files from the public folder**... now everything looks fine.